# How to update a Label on the UI thread/class within a selenium thread/class

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, selenium

So I have a problem on how to update a label on the UI thread from the selenium thread. As you see the selenium thread calls the "selenium" method that uses static methods(Login.UserLogin, Run.StartDriver) from other classes.

I can't seem to figure out how to change a label in this class from the login or run class. Sorry if the coding is amateur I just started learning c#.

```
public class Form1{

 private void startThread()
     {
        if (seleniumThread == null)
        {
          stopThread = false;
          seleniumThread = new Thread(() => selenium(userName,  passWord,
          cyclesWanted));

            seleniumThread.Start();
        }
    }

private void selenium(string user, string pass, int cycles)
    {

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        Login.UserLogin(driver, user, pass);

        Run.StartDriver(driver, cycles);

        if (stopThread)
        {
            driver.Quit();
            return; 
        }        
    }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    startThread();
     }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

1. In Login/Run class add static event
2. In Form class register to the event
3. When event will raising update the label by this.beginInvoke() function(because it's raise not UI thread).

   ```
     public class Login
       {

           public static event Action<string> TextChange;


           private static void OnTextChange(string newText)
           {
               if (TextChange != null)
                   TextChange(newText);
           }

           public static void  UserLogin(string driver, string userName,string password)
           {
               OnTextChange(userName);
           }

       }


       public class Form1
       {

           private void registerLoginEvent()
           {
               Login.TextChange += Login_TextChange;
           }

           private void Login_TextChange(string newText)
           {
               this.BeginInvoke(()=>label.text = newText);
           }

       }
   ```